# 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, cross-domain, django-cors-headers

I am working on project using Django and React using Rest Framework. I have set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True` in settings.py still i am getting error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/encrypt/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am using axios to post and get request. Suprisingly even after error post request is made but get request fails.
This is react file using axios

```
sendImage =()=> {
     this.activateSpinner()
     let formData = new FormData()
     formData.append('to_be_hidden', this.state.files[0], this.state.files[0].name)
     formData.append('used_to_hide', this.state.files[1], this.state.files[1].name)
     axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/encrypt/', formData, {
         headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
         }
     })
     .then(resp=>{
         this.getImageClass(resp)
         console.log(resp.data.id)
     })
     .catch(err=>{
         console.log("Code broke at send image")
         console.log(err)
     })
 }

 getImageClass =(obj)=> {
     axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/encrypt/${obj.data.id}/`, {
         headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
         }
     })
     .then(resp=>{
         this.setState({recentImage:resp})
         console.log(resp)
     })
     .catch(err=>{
        console.log("Code broke at get image")
        console.log(err)
    })
    this.deactivateSpinner()

 }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
     ...
    'corsheaders',
   
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
     ....
   
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
```

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely the issue from the backend side, I mean Django.

`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True` Once you set the `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` value, you also need to set the values for `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.
For instance
`ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`

Please take a look at the below links.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-django-cors-error

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS** to restrict other networks from accessing your end points; using **CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True** isn't advisable for production mode only.

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:8080",
"http://localhost:5173",
"http://localhost:3000",
```

]